# Load Test csript inside test in intern.js

Tags: javascript, intern

I'm trying to load test script according to custom argument passed through start command to start intern test.
To do this I'm trying to require the specific test script inside a test but i am getting `Attempt to require unloaded module` error.
This is my code set up. Can someone help on on this or sugest some alternative work around to make this work.

```
define(function (require) {
var intern = require('intern');
var AdvalentAutomationTestSuite = require('intern!object');
AdvalentAutomationTestSuite({
    name: 'Advalent Automation Test',

    'AdvalentTestSets': function () {
        return this.remote
            .then(function () {
                var product = intern.args.product;
                var script = 'Automation/TestScripts/FRG/' + product + '-Config';
                require(script)
            })
        },
    });
 });
```

Update:

Including `intern.js` file:

```
    define(function (require) {
var intern = require('intern');
console.log(intern)
return {
    proxyPort: 9000,

    proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
    defaultTimeout: 120000,
    capabilities: {
        'selenium_version': '2.48.2',
    },

    environments: [
        {browserName: 'chrome', version: '48', platform: ['WINDOWS'], chromeOptions: {args: ['start-maximized']}},
    ],

    maxConcurrency: 3,

    tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
    reporters: [
        {id: 'JUnit', filename: 'test-reports/report.xml'},
        {id: 'Runner'},
    ],

    Loaders: {
        'host-node': 'dojo/dojo',
        'host-browser': 'node_modules/dojo/dojo.js'
    },
    loaderOptions: {
        packages: [{name: 'intern-tutorial', location: '.'}]
    },

    functionalSuites: [

        'Automation/TestScripts/FRG/FRG-Config',
    ],
    defaultTimeout: 70000,
    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with the default loader, although as @Troopers points out, it's `loaders`, not `Loaders`. The problem is that you're doing a dynamic require with a computed name:

```
var script = 'Automation/TestScripts/FRG/' + product + '-Config';
require(script)
```

AMD loaders don't completely support the `require(script)` syntax since they don't load modules synchronously. When a module is written in CJS-compatibility mode, the loader fakes it by scanning the module code for `require` calls and then preloading and caching the modules before executing the module code. When the `require(script)` call is eventually executed, the preloaded module is returned.

When you use a computed module name, the loader can't preload the module being required, so the synchronous `require` call will fail. To load a module with a computed name you'll need to use the `require([ dependency ])` syntax, like:

```
var script = 'Automation/TestScripts/FRG/' + product + '-Config';
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    require([ script ], resolve);
});
```

At a higher level, though, it seems odd to be doing this in a test in the first place. It seems like something that should be handled at the module or config levels. For example, assuming `'Automation/TestScripts/FRG/' + product + '-Config'` is a functional test suite, the config could simply add that suite to the `functionalSuites` list if the required command line argument were provided.

Comment: Thanks @jaso0x43 this is enlightning. Thanks for shareing the knowledge .As for the the workaround for my problem I solved if from '`intern.js` file. I have also added my solution as an answer in this post. Please suggest if there's any better way to do this after reviewing my way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a loader in your configuration file :

```
loaders: {
    "host-node": "requirejs",
    "host-browser": "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
},
```

And install the npm package `requirejs`

The documentation is [here](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-useLoader)

Comment: do you mean that i have to install `require.js` packae to load the script . As I'm doing in above question?? Can you please elaborate .

Comment: And there's already a loader defined in my intern.js file. I'm updatin my question to include the intern.js file too.

Comment: Your loaders section is not correct in your intern.js file : use `loaders` instead of `Loaders`and use require.js loader instead of dojo loader

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Trooper . I marked jason0x43 answer as answer because it was more informative. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

After few hit and trial I managed to make it work by changing my `intern.js` as follows:

```
define(function (require) {
     var intern = require('intern');
      var product = intern.args.product
      return {


   functionalSuites: [
         'Automation/TestScripts/FRG/' + product + '-Config.js',
      ],
 // rest of config code ...
  }
});
```

Please suggest if there's any better way to do this.